# How to use Mongoose Aggregate to statistics sum and sort

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my schema:

```
let ORDER = new Schema({
    playername:String,
    serverUID:String,
    amount: Number,
    ADMIN_UID: String,
    status: Boolean,
    objid:Array,
})
```

I need to sort by ServerUID, then sort by objid and status is true, then calculate each amount.
pls help me! I really don't know how to work with data!

this is my first time asking question on the platform, if I have some ignored and impolite please forgive me!

Comment: You want to sort data when storing or when reading from the database ?

Comment: Sorry, @Jeremy Wu , I think that you didn't get my question. I am asking if you want to sort it while reading the data from the database or storing it in the database.

Comment: sort it while reading the data from the database!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort when reading data from MongoDB using `.sort()` function of JS.
Here is the code.
As you want to sort it using `serverUID` so, I set its value to `1`.

```
ORDER.find(function(err,result){
        if (!err){
            res.send(result);
        }else{
            res.send(err);
        }
    }).sort({serverUID: 1});
```

I